# Installing android market application in emulator 2.2

Tags: android, emulation

I have to build an application for push notifications in android.I read from the net tutorials that for push notifications C2DM is required.And for c2dm android market application needs to be installed.Can i plz have guidelines as how to install android market app in my emulator?

Comment: It is not possible to do that legally since the required .apk files are officially unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for implementation of push notification you don't really need the market app, 
take a look at this answer
[Android C2DM Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276342/android-c2dm-push-notification)

and the tutorial
http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/

Comment: i read the link:-http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html         In this 1.3 Requirements it is given that u need to install the market app.I am totally confused.Please guide me

Comment: Dear its two way process where you have to register your with c2dm that will give you a token that token is sent to your server or back-end and by using that token you can push the message on google cloud from you back-end. and then you will receive that message in your c2dm receiver