# Send Push notification in android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm, android-notifications

I want know something about push notifications. I am making a android apps and in this apps first user register to this android apps and data store on remote database which store on SQL SERVER and after that he logins. My question is that i want send notification to my android application user. How can i send notification?
So, please give me good example or example link.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just search stackoverflow for "[android] c2dm", there are plenty of example already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android C2DM Push Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276342/android-c2dm-push-notification)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google Cloud Messaging. [Here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) is the Android Documentation for this topic.
An overview:

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device, and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection. The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery to the target Android application running on the target device. GCM is completely free no matter how big your messaging needs are, and there are no quotas.

Comment: GCM has been replaced by Firebase Cloud Messaging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Google cloud messaging for this need. Cloud messaging is efficient in that it doesn't need any background service running all the time, saves battery and RAM.

[Google cloud messaging](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/)