# use of Push notification in android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

Can we use Push Notification in android.?

I have listen about [Comet Framework](http://cometd.org/) for Ajax Push technology

if Yes then How.?

if No then How to give Notification when some data changed at Server.

Any Tutorial for that..??

Thank you in advance

Comment: Another option if google cloud messaging, see here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that Stack Overflow already have that answer.
That a look here:
[Does Android support near real time push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification?rq=1)
and here: [Send Push notification in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751327/send-push-notification-in-android?rq=1)