# Implement Google Cloud Messaging in my android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications, implementation, google-cloud-messaging

I tested google cloud messaging example and now I would like to make a library project with this example and use it in an app. My app have an Activity with 3 fragment in a tabsadapter.

Can I have the app and the GCM library project separated or it's better to create a package with all the GCM part in my project?

Has anyone implemented GCM? Could anyone show me the right way? 
If you have any suggestions please write me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it separated, but your manifest.xml must be prepared to make a reference to a source code outside your package (writing the full path of the source, instead of .).

Comment: Ok, I'm changing my code. The biggest problem is the manifest, but thanks to this other answer I made it sample: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276342/android-c2dm-push-notification). Thank you for your answer